# Js: Error Handling in Async Await Case confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, es6-promise

This is not any conceptual question. just want to correct my logical side.

Case 1:

```
try {
  var to = await new IamErrorAlways()

  if (to && to instanceof Error) return to // is this correct way to handle.
} catch (error) {
  // report failure.
  return error
}
```

Case 2:

```
try {
  var to = await new IamErrorAlways()

  if (!to) throw new error('Expected to to return error') // or is this correct way to handle.
} catch (error) {

  // report failure.
  return error // <---- catch will return awaited error
}
```

Out of both which one is good.

Comment: It’s likely that neither one is correct. `await new …` never makes sense unless the constructor produces a thenable, and similarly `!to` can never be true unless `new IamErrorAlways()` is a thenable.

Comment: :p it make sense when your constructor is awaited and !to could be this itself..which should not be empty in return

Comment: What does “when your constructor is awaited” mean?

Comment: Constructor always returns immediate and then is what get resolved in end. i agree...but for cases when you want await method calls inside function body than you have to wrap it up with async...and if you do that than it became obvious to use await new functionName() else you have to resolve it.

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean, but it doesn’t sound like the only reason to use `await new`, which is the thenable thing that I mentioned. If `!('then' in new IamErrorAlways())`, `var to = await new IamErrorAlways();` is exactly equivalent to `await; var to = new IamErrorAlways();`, and probably equivalent to `var to = new IamErrorAlways();`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever promise `rejects`, it will not be returned as a `value` it will be thrown. And only way to check for thrown error is to catch it.

This is a typical example of a promise being rejected:

```
const promise = function() {
  return Promise.reject('hello');
};

(async () => {
  try {
    const promiseVal = await promise();
    console.log(promiseVal);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err+' from error');
  }
})();
```

So in this case the `console.log` in `try` block won't even execute. The catch will be executed printing `hello from error`.